# Square E-commerce Api integration to clients website

Tags: square-connect

Sorry if this is a simple question but I am trying to understand the best way to do this and I am new to Square development. I have a customer who has the Square chip card reader device on their cell phone and they are taking credit cards today. They also have a website which is using a oscommerce shopping cart and authorize.net gateway for processing orders on their website. What they want to do is just use Square and change the website so it integrates with their existing Square account. I understand the basic process of how to do this with the E-commerce API but I am a little confused on the developer / merchant Credentials.

This is a one off development for them so I do not think I want to use the oAuth method.

If they are a merchant today do they have to sign up under the developer area and create a app using the Application Dashboard so that they have a personal access token and application ID that I would use on their website? ( I already signed up and have a developer account)

What information about a sale is shown on their Square account once I integrate the secure SqPaymentForm payment form onto their website? Today all the details on the order are in the shopping cart such as what the customer ordered, the shipping address etc. Is this now going to appear on the Square account for them or do I still need to maintain this information in the shopping cart? It would be good if they could use a single interface such as the Square account.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't to use OAuth, you'll have to have the merchant go to the [Square Developer Portal](https://connect.squareup.com/apps/) and give you their personal access token and application id.

There are many different ways you can implement an online store, so where the information lives is all up to you. You probably want to keep your existing shopping cart functionality and just implement square for the payments, as that will likely be easiest and ensure you have all the data you want.